# Retornar duas funções em um evento onclick JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, funções

A minha pergunta é simples, suponha que eu possuo um botão, quando eu clico uma vez nele eu quero que execute uma função como podem ver abaixo:

```js
function ativar() {
  var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  btn[0].innerHTML="ativado";
}

function desativar() {
  var btn = document.getElementByTagName("button");
  btn[0].innerHTML="desativado";
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>exemplo</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <button onclick="ativar()">desativado</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

veja que a segunda função não é usada, ai está o problema, suponha que eu ativei o botão, dando um clique, executou a função ativar(), mas eu quero que quando eu dê um novo clique, ele execute a segunda função desativar().

Answer (score 2):

**Você pode tentar isso:**

```js
var stateButton = false;

function ativar() {
  var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  if ( stateButton == false ) {
    btn[0].innerHTML="ativado";
    stateButton = true;
  } else {
    btn[0].innerHTML="desativado";
    stateButton = false;
  }
}
```

```html
  <button onclick="ativar()">desativado</button>
```

Comment: Valeu, me ajudou muito, infelizmente tem gente que negativa a pergunta sem nem saber o contexto.